# Precompiling ASP.NET with Web Deploy from Team City

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, webdeploy

I currently have a Solution Build in Team City with the following command line arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package
```

This creates a web deployment package which is then deployed from another build step. The problem I'm having is that this package does not contain precompiled views, despite setting the appropriate settings in the the project properties in `Package/PublishWeb`.

I understand that publish profiles are not available through msbuild (which kind of sucks...), but even so I'm hoping this is still possible from the command line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.